# Changing text cursor color in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm using the dark mode in Chrome, so the background in Jupyter notebooks is black, and the text cursor is still black. Is there a way to change the text cursor (the blinking bar) in Jupyter notebooks to white, but keep everything else (all other colors) the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it by adding line to the file .jupiter/custom/custom.css

```
.cm-s-ipython .CodeMirror-cursor {border-left: 3px solid #838184 !important;}
```

Change #color as you want, as well as cursor width in pixels. However, try to avoid FFFFFF and 000000, because Chrome still converts them to black.
Also, there is one thing I couldn't fix, namely, autocomplete box with white font and highlighting color, so you can see all suggested rows, except initial.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit late but it's easier to add Jupyter Notebook / Jupyter Lab to your list of sites for Chrome to not change to dark, then use dark mode in Jupyter. You can download custom color themes for Jupyter if you don't like the built-in dark mode. I'm using Jupyter Lab and the URL I added to the list in Chrome was:

http://localhost:8888/lab

This fixed the dark invisible cursor issue for me.

Comment: Could you please tell me where I should put the URL in?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by downloading a jupyter dark theme.

pip install jupyterthemes

jt -t chesterish